# oracle sql conditional query with limit

Tags: java, oracle

This is my query:

```
select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE SEQ > 10 ROWNUM <=150
```

Getting the following exception:

> "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended"

Comment: missing an AND?

Comment: oops... added 'and'.. worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong,  correct query would be:

```
select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE SEQ > 10 AND ROWNUM <=150
```

Cause of error : Missing `AND` operator.